# DPLYR | How to summarise on character columns after doing group by?

Tags: r, dplyr

Currently I am using data.table package in R to summarise or collapse rows after grouping. I am wondering how I can achieve the same using dplyr and summarise all?

Using data table

```
    obs_dt <- obs_dt[, lapply(.SD, paste0, collapse=" "),
                     by=list(GroupID, Patient.Identifier, Gender, Age, Obs.Date,Location)]
```

Using Dplyr I have been able to achieve below, but not sure how to use summarise_all or summarise_each to achieve the same output:

```
initial_group <- c("Patient.Identifier", "Gender", "Age", "Obs.Date","Location")
dots = sapply(initial_group, . %>% {as.formula(paste0('~', .))})

obs_grp <- obs_grp %>% group_by_(.dots = dots) %>% summarise_each_(???/Not sure)
```

Comment: You need `summarise_each(funs(paste(., collapse=" ")))`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, it works, do you want to post it as answer?

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can change it to

```
obs_grp %>%
     group_by_(.dots = dots) %>%
     summarise_each(funs(paste(., collapse=" ")))
```